# Are there any pitfalls to storing collections of objects with unique ids as an associative array with ids as keys, rather than as a regular array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I've been following Backbone Collection's convention of having arrays of data objects and using _.find/findWhere etc to loop through the array, even when I wasn't using Backbone. However it seems like it would be more efficient to instead store them as an associative array with the id as keys if I know that they will be unique. Are there any pitfalls to this that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically:

```
var map = {};
map["someId"] = someObject;
map["someOtherId"] = someOtherObject;

// ...later to get the object:
var o = map["someId"];
```

If so, then the answer to "are there any pitfalls...I'm not seeing" is "no": Looking up properties on objects is a very common operation, which JavaScript engines do very quickly.

In fact, since [normal JavaScript arrays aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), it's **markedly** more efficient to look things up this way rather than storing them in arrays and using `forEach` or similar to find them. Every time you get an entry from an array (e.g., `a[0]` or whatever), that's a property access operation, just like looking up a property in an object. (In fact, that's **exactly** what it is, barring the JavaScript engine knowing it can optimize the operation.) Getting an element from one of the new [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) is faster because they really are arrays (although searching through them will still be non-trivial), but getting an element from a standard array is a property lookup on an object, so you might as well just do one lookup (on your map, using your key) instead.

---

(Side note: In JavaScript, the term "associative array" isn't usually used. It's just an object. Sometimes you also hear "map".)